# Code first, Update database EF6 Seed method not throwing an exception/error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

After updating one of my classes I ran Update-Database but I forgot to update my migration, and ended up with an empty database, the Seed method did not run as some of the properties were deleted.

My question is why is this so, shouldn't an exception/error be thrown?

My Seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(MyModel context)
    {
        context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(new UserRole
        {
            Name = "Admin"
        });
        context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(new UserRole
        {
            Name = "Ref"
        });
        context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(new UserRole
        {
            Name = "Dok"
        });
        context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(new UserRole
        {
            Name = "Fin"
        });

        context.SaveChanges();

        UserRole adminRole = context.Roles.Single(x => x.Name == "Admin");

        //Admin user
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(new User()
        {
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,

            Email = "admin",
            Password = Utils.GeneratePasswordHash("mypassword"),
            AccessFailedCount = 0,
            FirsName = "admin",
            LastName = "admin",

            Role = adminRole,

            LastLogin = DateTime.Now,
            IsAuthorized = true,

        });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I'm using EF6.
After updating the Seed method ran.

Comment: this fully depends on what your seed method looks like. your seed method will throw an exception, if it does at all for not right schema, and if it does get called.

Comment: is seed method called in your code, and on the right context?

Comment: So far it ran automatically with the Update-Database, I'm not running it manually.